# Can I detect if key is pressed in another window using java

Tags: java, background-process, onkeylistener

I want to create a program that would run in the background and everytime the user presses a key, the program would notify him in which language he is writing.
but I don't know how to detect (if possible) a key pressing in another unrealated program…
As far as I know keylisteners are only for my own java program when it has the focus, so it is not that useful for me…
(Sorry for my poor english)

Comment: You are trying to implement a key logger?

Comment: See above. You need to use JNI to accomplish this, which means your code may not be as portable as it would be otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook), it does this nicely.

Only caveat is that the key codes returned are different from those that Java uses IIRC.

I could show you a working program but Stack Overflow doesn't let me link to it because that would be "advertising". No time to produce an SSCCE for this space right now, sorry. I think JNativeHook is not hard to get into anyway.